# Detect assumption of preconnected unit numbers in Fortran

Tags: fortran

Traditionally, unit numbers 5 and 6 are connected to standard input and output, but for portability and standard compliance one should use `input_unit` and `output_unit` from `iso_fortran_env`.

Now, suppose we have a legacy that uses the 5/6 assumption and we want to update it to use `input_unit`/`output_unit` instead. Once we've changed all the obvious instances, is there some way we could detect less obvious ones (e.g. passing `6` as an argument to a subroutine, that then uses it as a unit number for writing) and hopefully prevent new ones from being introduced?

I thought that maybe one could:

a) Change the values of `input_unit` and `output_unit` to something different from 5 and 6. This might be an option in some compiler already?

b) Connect units 5 and 6 to something that will fail whenever it's used for reading or writing.

Is that possible? Or is there some other solution?

Comment: Possibly a dumb suggestion, but does running `grep -rn "\<5\>"` (i.e. searching for the complete token  "5") return few enough results to be able to verify by hand? And if not, can you make the grep increasingly specific until you only get file units?

Comment: @veryreverie The codebase is large enough that just searching for 5 or 6 is not very useful. I'm basically doing that on a file-by-file basis (as I clean up other stuff), but I'm sure to miss some instances.

Comment: Rather than initially changing them to input_unit/output_unit, change it to a file and see what input/output remains? Once you've tracked them all down then change it to the iso_fortran_env values. I'm assuming your test suite has sufficient coverage as well